# How to insert multiitems in slot NuxtJS 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I need to insert several slides. through a slot, the slides can have components. I used to use v-node along with render, but that no longer works in vue3, how can I bring out a similar functionality in vue3 ?

oldcode:

```
.swiper-wrapper
    .swiper-slide(v-for="(item, i) in $slots.default" :key="i")
      v-nodes(:vnodes="item")

components: {
    VNodes: {
      functional: true,
      render: (h, ctx) => ctx.props.vnodes
    }
  },
```

New Code:

```
.swiper-section
  swiper(:slides-per-view="3" :space-between="50" @swiper="onSwiper" @slideChange="onSlideChange")
    swiper-slide(v-for="(item, i) in $slots.default()" :key="i")  
      span {{  item  }}
```

The item returns an object:

```
{
  "__v_isVNode": true,
  "__v_skip": true,
  "type": "p",
  "props": null,
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "scopeId": null,
  "slotScopeIds": null,
  "children": "123",
  "component": null,
  "suspense": null,
  "ssContent": null,
  "ssFallback": null,
  "dirs": null,
  "transition": null,
  "el": null,
  "anchor": null,
  "target": null,
  "targetAnchor": null,
  "staticCount": 0,
  "shapeFlag": 9,
  "patchFlag": -1,
  "dynamicProps": null,
  "dynamicChildren": null,
  "appContext": null,
  "ctx": null
}
```

How can I implement this on naxt3 ? In slots can be multiple dom elements and components